# Replace image in drupal 8 block

Tags: drupal-8

could someone please enlighten me with an answer regarding this issue, i'm trying to replace an image in drupal 8 block but i can't find a way to make this happen. do i have to find the old image in the administration menu and change it ? could someone please help me. I've just started working with drupal and i'm completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Google Chrome Web developer tool to inspect the image location. "Right click, then choose inspect, then inspect the image to see where the location of the image is."

Another thing that you can do is to go to the block itself admin/structure/block.

Do you know which block that you are trying to modify?

Comment: thank you for your reply. fortunately, i figured it out. but im stuck on something else, i want to change the favicon of the site so i went to appearence>settings and i checked out the default favicon that comes with drupal and i uploaded the favicon that i want to add but nothing changed. Have you encounterd such problem before. thanks a lot for your reply in advance .

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your reply. fortunately, i figured it out. but im stuck on something else, i want to change the favicon of the site so i went to appearence>settings and i checked out the default favicon that comes with drupal and i uploaded the favicon that i want to add  but nothing changed. Have you encounterd such problem before.  thanks a lot for your reply in advance .